# I have to add a progress bar that will show the user progress of the download that my Visual Studio C# Windows forms application will do

Tags: c#

I need to make a progressbar that'll track the download progress in my code but i don't know how to do it.

```
string url = "https://discovertheme.net/dosyalar/Appserv%208.6.0.exe";
string downloadsFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + "\Downloads";
string fileName = "Appserv 208.6.0.exe";
string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(downloadsFolder, fileName);

using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    try
    {
        webClient.DownloadFile(url, filePath);
        MessageBox.Show("İndirme başarıyla yüklendi!", "Bildirim", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Dosyayı yüklenirken bir hata oluştu: {ex.Message}", "Hata", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

I tried to get help from ChatGPT but i have failed as well as the AI itself.

Comment: There's an event when the download is progressing [Check the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged?view=net-8.0)

Comment: Also mind this note: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-8.0#remarks